# LAMP on Raspberry Pi to host a web server

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql, raspberry-pi, web-hosting, lamp

First question ever on the site. 
Forgive me in advance for my very limited knowledge on the subject, I am fairly new on hosting web servers, databases, and just Raspberry Pis in general. I want to host a WordPress website on my Raspberry Pi and I installed all the software for it: Apache, PHP, MariaDB (the new MySQL, I'm guessing?), and WordPress...(I'm most probably missing so many more or I poorly configured them), and everything was going good. I would search up the local web address of my Pi and after doing the LAMP server configuration I get some "Index of /" output and just empty columns that say "Name, Last modified, Size and Description". What is this? I'm following this tutorial: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/host-wordpress-raspberry-pi/. Hopefully the information I gave is enough to explain myself. I'm a noob at this and all input is deeply appreciated. I'm here to learn. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> After doing the LAMP server configuration, I get some "Index of /" output and just empty columns that say "Name, Last modified, Size and Description". What is this?

This is an automatic directory listing. This is what is displayed when there is no "root" document in a directory (ex. `index.html`), assuming the feature to display directory contents is enabled in Apache. For what it's worth, it sounds like there are no files in your root web folder.

> So I just need to populate the folder with `.html` files?

Apache maintains a list of files that it will serve by default when a directory is requested, so not just any random e.g. `.html` file will do. By convention, these default files are often named `index`, along with an appropriate extension for the file type (ex. either `index.htm` or `index.html` for `.html` files).

`DirectoryIndex` is the Apache directive that defines any files that are served automatically for a directory request and is often found in the main Apache configuration file (`httpd.conf`) ex:

```
DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php index.cgi
```

A file with a name from this list is required to be present in a directory to prevent Apache from returning an automatic directory listing.

For example:

*ex. index.html is missing (automatic directory listing)*

```
bar.html
baz.html
foo.html
```

*Result:*

[image: Missing index.html - Screenshot]

*ex. index.html is present (no automatic directory listing)*

```
bar.html
baz.html
foo.html
index.html
```

*Result:*

[image: index.html Present - Screenshot]

> How do web developers use web building sites like WordPress, etc.?

The files in a directory do not need to be `.html` files. Some or all can be script files (ex. `.php`) or even other executable files (ex. `.cgi`). So tools such as WordPress can simply be extracted and placed into a directory "as-is".

Regarding the behavior in original question, assuming that Apache was configured correctly to run PHP scripts, there might be a file called `index.php` that Apache would execute by default when a directory was requested.

---

*And if you download WordPress directly as a [zip](https://wordpress.org/latest.zip) or [tar.gz](https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz) file, you will indeed see an `index.php` file in the root of those extracted files.*

---

Comment: Thank you so much! So I just need to populate the folder with html files? If that is the case, then how to web developers use web building sites like WordPress, etc.? I appreciate your patience in advance.

Comment: You're welcome. And not a problem. =) I have updated my answer. But in short, there is a list of files defined in your Apache configuration that Apache will serve by default, rather than displaying an automatic directory listing. For WordPress, ideally all you should need to do to use it is place its files in your root web directory (rather than any `.html` files). If that doesn't work, you may need adjust your Apache configuration.

Comment: Great input! I'm slowly getting it :) however I might be wrong... So it's only a matter of dumping web files (html, php, etc.) in the root directory and it'll work? The root directory in my pi is `/var/www/html/` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Maybe I should add some more context. So my pi broke yesterday and I had to reinstall the OS and I ended up downloading apache2, php, and MariaDB again, and downloaded this database interface called phpMyAdmin in the meantime. It works fine I'm guessing...I search up my pi's IP and it gives me the Apache2 Debian Default Page still, so I have not deleted anything just yet. 

So downloading WordPress is the final step if I'm not mistaken...do you recommend any specific sequence of commands to install and link WP to the root directory? I don't mind breaking my pi again, but I'd prefer not to :D

Comment: *"So it's only a matter of dumping web files (html, php, etc.) in the root directory and it'll work?"* - Assuming you followed steps 1-3 in the article linked in the original question, roughly, yes. Step 4 is the WordPress installation. The suggestion to remove the contents of `/var/www/html/` with `sudo rm *`, then move the extracted contents of WordPress to that same directory with `sudo mv wordpress/* .` is exactly what we are talking about (i.e. just dropping the files into the web root). However, to avoid permission issues, make certain to run `sudo chown -R www-data: .` after the move.

Comment: And yes, best to avoid breaking things. It makes a lot of extra work. ;)

Comment: If you really need to check things ahead of time, simply create a file called e.g.`info.php` and place a single line in it as `<?php phpinfo()?>`. Drop this in `/var/www/html/` and navigate to the LAN IP of the Pi with `/info.php` afterwards. Assuming there are no permission issues or other errors, you should see a printout of information regarding your PHP installation. This means that Apache is processing `.php` files correctly.

Comment: You sir are a champion lol thank you! I managed to download Wordpress and allowed myself to edit the folder. The website is looking pretty good so far, hopefully its not too resource intense for the pi :/

Now its only a matter of posting it online i guess

Comment: Lol! Again, you're welcome.  =) I am sincerely glad you got it working. Regarding resources, if the site is low traffic (i.e. just a personal site) I would think the Pi could likely handle it. But you never really know until you try. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯